CSS animation on svg elements triggering recalcula style and layerize
when applying CSS animation on SVG element,
the performance recording shows that, it triggers lots of "Recalculate Style", "Layerize" tasks.


.svg-wrap {
        animation: rotateAni 1s linear infinite;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }

      @keyframes rotateAni {
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="svg-wrap">
        <rect
          width="100"
          height="100"
          fill="none"
          stroke="red"
          stroke-width="5"
        />
      </svg>





but if I wrap the SVG with a div and apply the animation on the div, it doesn't have these tasks...


.svg-wrap {
        animation: rotateAni 1s linear infinite;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }

      @keyframes rotateAni {
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
<div class="svg-wrap">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
        <rect
          width="100"
          height="100"
          fill="none"
          stroke="red"
          stroke-width="5"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>




can someone help to explain why?

99% of the web is html, 1% is SVG, canvas etc. Which do you think browser developers spend more time optimising?
